# How to install Captvty in Playonlinux

Tags: playonlinux

(I post this in order to provide an answer.)

I have posted under [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/848511/47206) an answer on how to use [Captvty](http://captvty.fr/) with Wine, and it is a rather complex procedure.

I wander if Playonlinux can make things easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will try to update this over time. Tested in Mint 18.1 and Solus OS.

---

In Playonlinux:

- Configure: *New*, select 32bit version, name it without spaces (e.g.Captvty)
- Selecting the new drive, go to *Miscellaneous* tab and select 'Open virtual's drive directory', and copy the Captvty program folder (downloaded and un-packed, as it is a *portable* program) into the folder `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Captvty/drive_c/Program Files`.
- Again selecting the drive, go to the tab *Install new components* and install one by one: **vcrun2010, dotnet40, gdiplus, Internet Explorer 8**
- Under the *General* tab, select to make a new shortcut, then select the Captvty.exe file and give it a name.

At this point, downloading a video should work; in order to play directly the video, the Flash player is needed: download the Windows 7, Internet Explorer version from [here](http://get.adobe.com/en/flashplayer/otherversions/), then:

- Install it in Playonlinux - Configure, select the Captvty drive, *Miscellaneous* tab, then 'Run a .exe in this virtual drive'.

Selecting Configure - General tab, the Wine version can be changed. I have tested with 1.7 and 1.9.

---

There seem to be some limitations as to the arte-tv videos (on alternative methods to get the arte-tv videos, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/184904/47206)); some Captvty versions do not list them at all, the latest one tested (2.5.8.1) can list and download them but cannot play them with the Flashplayer.

---

The above answer is based on ideas from [here](http://racoon97.blogspot.fr/2014/11/installer-captvty-sur-ubuntu-14.html) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i84mmzUZWjs).